# MYSQL - Update using while loop

Tags: mysql

```
declare c int 
set c = 1
while c<700 do
update users set profile_display_name = concat(substring(first_name,1,1), last_name) 
        where profile_display_name is null and id between ((c-1)*10000+1) and (c*10000);
SET c = c+1;
End while ;
```

I am getting error. near declare and end while statement. Where am I making mistake??

Comment: I tried, I am from SQL background. I couldn't guess anything. Any advise?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Is this code, part of a trigger or a stored procedure? What error do you get?

Comment: You probably need `;` after each statement: `declare c int; set c=1;`

Comment: You haven't answered @ypercube's previous question. Is this code part of a stored routine?

Comment: looks awkward.. btw, shouldn't all this be enclosed in transaction? Every time you make an operation with more than one sql query, it is not guaranteed to be atomic. I don't know how this is taken by sql but it's likely that you must use transaction.

Comment: @nnichols , I want to run the script as it is however, I see that it is forcing me to create SP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This Works much better for me

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`ops`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `myproc`()
BEGIN
DECLARE c INT;
SET c = 1;
WHILE c < 700 DO 
SELECT CONCAT('Loop #:', c) ;

update users 
set profile_display_name = concat(substring(first_name,1,1), last_name) 
where (profile_display_name is null or profile_display_name = '')
and id between ((c-1)*10000+1) and (c*10000); 

commit;

SET c=c+1; 

END WHILE;
END
```

Comment: Why you need commit there?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how it would be defined as a stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name()
BEGIN

    DECLARE c int ;                      --- added ;
    SET c = 1 ;                          --- added ;
    WHILE c<700 DO
      UPDATE users 
        SET profile_display_name = concat(substring(first_name,1,1), last_name) 
        WHERE profile_display_name IS NULL
          AND id BETWEEN ((c-1)*10000+1) AND (c*10000);
      SET c = c + 1 ;
    END WHILE ;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Nicely done. One addition actually helped me more is a COMMIT statement before SET c=c+1;

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL compound statements and flow control structures can only be used in stored routines - [MySQL Compound-Statement Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html)