# Query to perform bulk update on indexed column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 4 million records where unique_value is null. This column is indexed and I am trying to update 4 million records with random numbers.

```
CREATE TABLE `auto` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `unique_value` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Table

```
Id     unique_value
1       132643635
2       132643634
3       132643636
4       132643637
5       NULL
6       NULL
```

Query1:

```
UPDATE auto a
SET a.unique_value =
  (SELECT FLOOR(100000 + RAND() * 888888) AS rand_value
   FROM auto
   WHERE unique_value NOT IN
       (SELECT unique_value
        FROM auto
        WHERE unique_value IS NOT NULL));
```

Can someone suggest if there is a better way to perform this update?

Comment: Why do you need a `unique_value` column? The primary key `id` is already unique.

Comment: You need `LIMIT 1` in the subquery. Otherwise it generates millions of rows, which will cause an error when trying to assign it.

Comment: Primary key ID is unique and there is another unique column in the table which I am trying to update. The subquery check is to make sure that the randomly generated number is not present in the table

Comment: I know what you're trying to do. I just wonder why you need two unique values.

Comment: If you want something that's not sequential, how about `MD5(id)`?

Comment: The value should be a 20 digit number which is not present in the unique_value column

Comment: You should use a loop that generates a number, tests if it's in use, and updates the row. So do this in a stored procedure with a `WHILE` loop.

Comment: Do you have any example that you could point me to?

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915315/mysql-update-using-while-loop

Comment: I found that by googling "mysql procedure loop update"

Comment: Why not using 100000000000000000000 as ur first entry and keep adding 1 in a loop ? all numbers will be unique.